# Incorrect Syntax on a Table in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm building a database for a site and I keep getting an incorrect syntax error for this portion of it:

```
    CREATE TABLE posts (
        pid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        title VARCHAR(255),
        body VARCHAR,
        user_id INT REFERENCES users(uid),
        author VARCHAR REFERENCES users(username),
        date_created TIMESTAMP
        like_user_id INT[] DEFAULT ARRAY[]::INT,
        likes INT DEFAULT
    );
```

When I put a comma after `TIMESTAMP`, it then switches the error message to after the `INT []` on the like_user_id line.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  The syntax is definitely not standard SQL.  Also, your foreign key references do not make sense.  Why would you have separate columns for `user_id` and `author` with two references to the same table using different columsn?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Postgres (which the syntax is closest to), you can use something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    pid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    body VARCHAR(255),
    author_uid INT REFERENCES users(uid),
    date_created TIMESTAMP,
    like_user_id INT[] DEFAULT '{}'::INT[],
    likes INT DEFAULT 0
);
```

Notes:

- There is no need for a separate foreign key reference for the user and the name.  Use a `join` to get the name.
- You need a comma after the `timestamp`.
- You need an appropriate expression for an empty array for `like_user_id`.
- You need a default value for `likes`.

I also recommend putting in lengths for the `varchar()`.  I mean, you can skip all the lengths if you like (Postgres allows that), but I don't see a reason to have lengths in some columns and no lengths in others.

Answer (score 0):

Cast `ARRAY[]::INT` => `ARRAY[]::INT[]`:

```
 CREATE TABLE posts (
        pid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        title VARCHAR(255),
        body VARCHAR,
        user_id INT REFERENCES users(uid),
        author VARCHAR REFERENCES users(username),
        date_created TIMESTAMP,
        like_user_id INT[] DEFAULT array[]::int[],
        likes INT DEFAULT 0
    );
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dfbdf90564d856b875b175d0cc22acd2)**